# Как удалить строку в SQLite через C# (.NET WinForms)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

Мне надо удалить строку по `rowid`, но по той или иной причине, SQLite не принимает мой **запрос**. В SQLite строка не удаляется.
`ExecuteNonQuery` возвращает **0**.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int itemIndex = this.listView1.FocusedItem.Index + 1;
    GuestsDatabase guestsDB = new GuestsDatabase();
    string query = "DELETE FROM GuestsList WHERE rowid = " + itemIndex + ";";
    MessageBox.Show(query);
    SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, guestsDB.sqliteCon);
    guestsDB.OpenConnection();
    var result = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Возвращает 0 
    guestsDB.CloseConnection();
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
```

Класс **GuestsDatabase:**

```
public class GuestsDatabase
{
    public SQLiteConnection sqliteCon;

    public GuestsDatabase()
    {
        sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=guestsDB.sqlite3");

        if (!File.Exists("./guestsDB.sqlite3"))
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("guestsDB.sqlite3");
        }

    }
        
    public void OpenConnection()
    {
         if (sqliteCon.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
         {
            sqliteCon.Open();
         }
    }

        
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (sqliteCon.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqliteCon.Clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а вы уверены что у вас в базе есть строка с правильным itemIndex, проверяли?

Comment: проверяйте правильность значения `itemIndex`. Поставьте точку останова на строку `GuestsDatabase guestsDB = new GuestsDatabase();` запустите, и посмотрите значение этой переменной, оно правильное? Есть ли такая запись с таким `rowid`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten , в **Форме** я использую **ViewList** с таблицей всех строк в **БД**, так  как счёт в **ViewList** начинается с **0**, я инкрементирую itemIndex, и получаю строку в **БД** через **rowid**, а строки с нужным мне rowid существуют, но не получают запрос.

Comment: Ну, то есть вы отказываетесь заниматься отладкой? А хотите готовый ответ? Тогда я вас разочарую....

Comment: @Bulson Да, значение **itemIndex** правильное, там хранится как раз тот **rowid** который мне нужен. В коде в котором я прикрепил даже есть проверка значения **itemIndex** после создание запроса **query**.

Comment: Ваш подход изначально неверный. `FocusedItem.Index`, как вы сами правильно пишете, начинается с 0. Между тем айдишники в базе постепенно нарастут и станут тысячами и миллионами. Вы же не будете все записи сразу грузить в листвью? / Нужно из листвью извлекать нужный привязанный объект и уже из него брать id.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, это понятно, но мой вопрос заключается в том, как должен выглядеть запрос, чтобы удалить строку из Базы Данных. Я и без `ListView` пытался, но видимо я пишу не правильный запрос

Comment: Никаких ошибок в коде не видно, всё сделано правильно. Единственно, с чем может быть проблема: в sql-запрос передаётся неправильный id, которого нет в БД.

Comment: А как была создана таблица? Покажите запрос `create table`.

Comment: Ай, заморочили вы всем (и себе голову). Дефолтный `rowid` в sqlite начинается с **единицы**, я только что проверил. Ваша ошибка именно в ItemIndex. Выполните запрос в консоли к своей БД: `select rowid from GuestsList;` - какие там числа?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо что пытаетесь помочь. Почему-то какую бы я строку не выбрал, запрос `select rowid from GuestsList;`  возвращает -1 . С чем это связано?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = @"Data Source = .......\test.db";
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        
        int id = 2; 
        string sql = $"DELETE FROM table WHERE id = {id}";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Рекомендации**

Используйте `using` для кода, работающего с БД. Это обезопасит, не нужно каждый раз писать команды с Close() и Dispose().

Comment: `SQLiteCommand` тоже нужно обернуть в `using`! Что ж вы сами не следуете своим рекомендациям?

Comment: Не составляйте sql-запросы с помощью конкатенации/интерполяции строк. Используйте параметризованные запросы.

Comment: Вообще, у автора проблема в том, что он передаёт неправильный айдишник в запрос.

Comment: "SQLiteCommand тоже нужно обернуть в using!" Главное чтобы в using был весь этот контекст, а уж дальше без фанатизма.